# MessageBox not showing any text in C Sharp

Tags: c#

my message box is supposed pop up and ask the user if they want to download a new version of the application and if they say no, it exits and tells them that they need to download a new copy to continue. If they say yeah, it opens a browser to the aforementioned web address. Right now, the message box pops up and nothing appears. However, whenever I gave the code to my friend and he tried it, it worked. What's wrong here? I compiled with Microsoft Framework 4.0.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProjectTest
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1_FormClosing();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing()
   {
   const string message =
    "There's an updated version of this program available. Would you like to download now?";
const string caption = "Please update";
var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
                             MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                             MessageBoxIcon.Question);

// If the no button was pressed ...
if (result == DialogResult.No)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Program will close now. If you want to use this program please update to the newest version.", "Please update");
    this.Close();
}
else if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
    this.Close();
}
}

    }
}
```

Comment: your code seems like it should work.  The friend you gave it to, was he running the same OS as you?  the size and style of widgets changes from version to version an cause things to display differently.

Comment: The thing is, I ran and compiled this on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2008 and 2010, it didn't work. I then ran it with VS 2010 on XP and it still didn't work. Tried 4.0 and 3.5, it still didn't work. At a lost for words right now.

Comment: I made that change, the messagebox just still shows up blank.

Comment: Can you  try using '@' string literal in **Process.Start**

Comment: Are you saying nothing showed up in the message box or the web browser did not come up?

Comment: Nothing shows up in the message box. It's just blank.

Comment: Did you try rebuilding the project? Right-click on your project name in VS and click "Rebuild".

Comment: Are using a different theme to your desktop, If yes try reverting to the windows basic theme and check out

Comment: Does the windows theme dictate that much over the compiled program?

Comment: its style is dependent on windows,so it could be causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProjectTest
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing()
   {
   const string message =
    "There's an updated version of this program available. Would you like to download now?";
const string caption = "Please update";
var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
                             MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                             MessageBoxIcon.Question);

// If the no button was pressed ...
if (result == DialogResult.No)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Program will close now. If you want to use this program please update to the newest version.", "Please update");
                e.Cancel = false;
}
else if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
                e.Cancel = false;
}
}

    }
}
```

Comment: Error 1 Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

Comment: OK~ I post the whole code, I think you might be missing some "}" or other sign or wrong namespace to get these wrong message. **Error 1 Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct**